# PHP drop down from JSON populating, but text is invisible

Tags: php, json, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to create a drop down of items from a JSON file located on a remote server. The drop down appears to be populating (as there are options to choose from), but the text is not visible. I have attempted changing the style color (worth a try, right?) and multiple browsers.

```
<?php
echo '<select name="version" style="width: 300px">';
$url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

foreach($jsonDataObject->versions as $option){
    echo '<option value=' . $option->type . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

?>

Thanks in advance for any assistance offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not populating the display text

```
echo "<option value= { $option->type } >{$option->type}</option>";
```

This is a little different from your statement, but the logic is the same. You need to write some text between option tags

```
<option value="val">displayText</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like-

```
echo '<option value=' . $option->type . '>'.$SOME_VALUE_HERE.'</option>';
 //                                      ^
```